# AntiForgery token is null when sending token via ajax call in page load of action having no params

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Ajax call to send a forgery token in page load.

```
@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }

@Html.AntiForgeryToken();

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                '__RequestVerificationToken': token
            },
            url: "Test",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                '__RequestVerificationToken': token
            },
            success: function (results) {
                //alert(url);
                alert("Success");
            },

            error: function (e) {
                alert(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

The contoller action is like this

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Test()
    {
        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
```

Error is - The required antiforgery token is null.